# Flatpak vs apt plans

Tags: flatpak

This is merely a question, and I'm not really sure where to place it. If there is a more appropriate place, please let me know.

Elementary has been slowly moving to integrate Flatpak. I personally do not agree with sandboxing solutions and make my best efforts to avoid them.

Elementary moving to distribute os basic apps such as terminal, files, settings, and the likes via Flatpak (or similar solutions for that matter) will mean I will leave Elementary os.

Does a timeline of this move exists? Or what apps exactly will end up in Flatpak?

Does this move mean they will not be available via apt? Can one possibly replace the Flatpak ones in the future?

I understand there are benefits to Flatpak. But there are also drawbacks. None of the benefits are problems to me today, and the drawbacks will definitely be.

Thanks.

Comment: To bring this back to the top now that eOS 6 is out, and I've installed it in a VM to have a look, let me ask slightly differently: What apps in the base iso for eOS6 are installed as flatpak? Can we get traditionally packaged apps into App Centre? It's relatively empty. I'm concerned, eOS is a UNIX desktop OS. I will surely use a few flatpak apps, but cannot afford to have everything from terminal to chrome browser running every so slightly different libraries and swap thrashing. If this means that eOS 6 is not for me, fair enough. In that case then, what is the maintenance plan for eOS 5.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reminder @Jeff. Just installed eOS 6 in a VM, here is what is packed with flatpak out off box.

- Calculator
- Camera
- Screenshot
- Tasks (A new app, I believe it is already in App Center for eOS 5.
- Mesa
- GNOME Web
- Evince

I would prefer none to be, but none of them are really critical, to me anyway.